# Singleton method usage in Python to create one instance in logging package

Tags: python, class, logging, singleton

Coding this in Python as a newbie and trying to understand how to create a single instance of a logging class in a separate module. I am trying to access the logging module from my python script. So, I have different files in this automation script and I am trying to record the logs in a file and displaying the logs in the console at the same time so I would be utilizing two handlers namely: FileHandler() and StreamHandler(). The initialization of logger is in a different file called debugLogs.py and I am accessing this file from multiple Python modules running the script. But if the separate modules call debugLogs.py it creates multiple instances of the logger which means it gets printed multiple times which is not what I want. That is why I need to use singleton method to create just one instance. How do you suggest I go about doing that? I have included my version of debugLogs.py in this code and I have shown

```
#debugLogs.py

import logging
import logging.handlers

#open readme file and read name of latest log file created
def get_name():
    with open("latestLogNames.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            pass
        latestLog = line
    logfile_name = latestLog[:-1]
    return logfile_name


class Logger(object):
    _instance = None
    def __new__(self, logfile_name):
        if not self._instance:
            self._instance = super(Logger, self).__new__(self)
            logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
            logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
            formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
            file_handler = logging.FileHandler(logfile_name)
            file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
            stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
            logger.addHandler(file_handler)
            logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
        return self._instance
```

So get_name() gets the latest log name already indicated in the readme file latestLogNames.txt and inputs the logs in the latest log file already there.
I understand that my singleton class code is not right and I am confused on how to initialize the whole class structure. But somehow I would have to pass that logfile_name value to that class. So I am planning to call this logger from a different module with something like this:

```
#differentModule.py

import debugLogs
logger = debugLogs.Logger(debugLogs.get_name())
```

And then I would use logger.info("...") to print the logs as well as store it in the file. Please tell me how to restructure the debugLogs.py and how to call it from different modules of my script.

Comment: i strongly suggest you learn python 3 if you are new to python. python 2 has reached its end of life.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I will but I am working on a legacy code so for this I have to use Python 2.7. Any solutions???

Comment: [`logging.getLogger("my_logger")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger) already does all you want. configure the logger it returns once (usually when your program starts up) and get that logger anywhere in your code with `getLogger("my_logger")`.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Do you mean initialize the logger by doing logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) and then setting level and formatter etc. by doing logger.setLevel(logging.INFO) and formatter = logging.formatter('%(message)s') in each module? In that way I won't even need debugLogs.py. But I have a lot of modules and so to stop repetition of code I created debugLogs.py so that all the other modules can call it and get logger configured. But if it calls from different modules that creates different instances which is not what I want since that prints out multiple lines

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I am also facing similar problem where I can't seem to solve the problem of multiple instance being created. The singleton method should work correctly but how to implement it in the right way?

Comment: no. you need to configure the logger only once. `getLogger("my_logger")` returns a singleton.

Comment: if you want to create a singleton for something else, this is an option: https://riptutorial.com/python/example/1302/singletons-using-metaclasses